# Uploaded Image in django not working during production

Tags: python, django

During development my uploaded images are showing, but on production they are not.

Here are the codes:

```
#settings.py
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/eakdev/webapps/my_static'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/eakdev/webapps/my_static/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

#urls.py When I add this during development my images are showing correctly
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

#base.html
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ project.preview.url }}" alt="">
```

After reading some of the questions related to this, I think the reason why its not working is that my code is using dev server to serve the media files, which is only good for development. What do i change so that it would work in production?

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to serve media files in production is to set up your front-end webserver or CDN to serve them.

For example in nginx you'd include the following section in your server configuration:

```
location /media/ {                        # Should match MEDIA_URL
    alias /path/to/mysite.com/media/;     # Should match MEDIA_ROOT
}
```

And in Apache:

```
Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/  # MEDIA_URL MEDIA_ROOT

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>     # MEDIA_ROOT
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

These would be the bare minimum directives and you can of course do a lot more with caching, access control, etc.

Comment: could you be more specific or an example maybe, it's kinda my first time deploying

Comment: If it's your first time deploying, I'd recommend working through one of the step-by-step tutorials, e.g. [Setting up Django and uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) or [Setting up Django with Nginx, Gunicorn, virtualenv, supervisor and PostgreSQL](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/). There is also [quite a bit on the subject at Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/search?q=django+nginx). If you have follow-up questions they may be a better fit there.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the links, i was able to fix my problem by trial and error but still don't know the reason behind it. Be going through the links you suggested and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In settings.py i commented these lines:

```
#MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/prk/Documents/prakhar/mysite/media'
#MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and added these lines:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "www", "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

When you will run server on localhost it will give error but in production it will work fine.

my project structure is:
/Wrapper/mysite/( ... *and* ... *and*  manage.py *and* mysite *and* ...)

in wrapper directory i have a folder named www and inside it a folder named media.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it would be better if you can edit your post with your directory structure as `tree`. That would be more helpful.